# Dimension Mismatch Error during dot product in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have two matrices `user_vecs` and `item_vecs`

I am trying to take the dot product of the two to build a recommendation engine:

The shape of the two vectors are as follows:

```
user_vecs.shape
(20051, 20)

item_vecs.shape
(20,1808)
```

When I take the dot product of the transpose as follows:

```
a = user_vecs.dot(item_vecs.transpose())
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-f4cd01978711> in <module>
----> 1 a = user_vecs.dot(item_vecs.transpose())

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in dot(self, other)
    362 
    363         """
--> 364         return self * other
    365 
    366     def power(self, n, dtype=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    479         if issparse(other):
    480             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
--> 481                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
    482             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    483 

ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

I understand that the dimensions of the two matrices are not matching, but the transpose should have fixed that. Why am I still getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `user_vecs` and `item_vecs` are matrices, not vectors, since both the shapes are of two dimensions. It seems like you are trying to multiply both the matrices, so you can simply use `user_vecs.dot(item_vecs)`. No need to transpose `item_vecs`. You can also use `np.matmul(user_vecs, item_vecs)`.  Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562986/numpy-matrix-vector-multiplication) thread for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically speaking this is matrix dot product. i.e. the number of columns in `user_vecs` must match the number of rows (lines) in `item_vecs`. In this case the matching is already established since performing a dot product on (20051, 20) by (20,1808) is mathematically feasible. You need to just to put on the product directly.

**Transpose is the source of the error in the code above**

```py
a = user_vecs.dot(item_vecs)
```